# Regex to allow A-Z, - and '

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get this Regex to work to validate a Name field to only allow A-Z, ' and -.

So far I am using this which is working fine apart from it wont allow an apostrophe.

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z'-]+/",$firstname)) {
            // do something
        }
```

I would like it to only allow A-Z, - (dash) and an ' (apostrophe). It works for the A-Z and the - but still wont work for the '

Could someone please provide an example?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this regex also allows "abc123"

Comment: @Evert: And `$@#$%@#$%&*(*&){}//;;`, too. :)

Comment: Your code works for me as is. Can you add an example of `$firstname` that fails to match?

Comment: Daniel'Blackmore using "/[^a-zA-Z'-]+/"

Comment: @Daniel, I've updated my answer with your sample string. I suspect you are just using the wrong side of the if/else...

Comment: I hope this is not a database for real people. Otherwise, please read this: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Z'-]+$/",$firstname)) {
    // do something
}
```

The caret `^` inside a character class `[]` will negate the match. The way you have it, it means if the `$firstname` contains characters other than `a-z`, `A-Z`, `'`, and `-`.

Comment: OP doesn't want lower case chars

Comment: "All chars are valid" is logically equivalent to "No char is invalid" by the [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) You expression is fine, but it's basically the same as the original one.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: You are right, I have just removed the lowercase class, and turned it around.

Answer (score 2):

Your code already does what you want it to:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    // Valid
    'Jim',
    'John',
    "O'Toole",
    'one-two',
    "Daniel'Blackmore",

    // Invalid
    ' Jim',
    'abc123',
    '$@#$%@#$%&*(*&){}//;;',

);

foreach($data as $firstname){
    if( preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z'-]+/",$firstname) ){
        echo 'Invalid: ' . $firstname . PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo 'Valid: ' . $firstname . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

... prints:

```
Valid: Jim
Valid: John
Valid: O'Toole
Valid: one-two
Valid: Daniel'Blackmore
Invalid:  Jim
Invalid: abc123
Invalid: $@#$%@#$%&*(*&){}//;;
```

The single quote does not have any special meaning in regular expressions so it needs no special treatment. The minus sign (`-`), when inside `[]`, means *range*; if you need a literal `-` it has to be the first or last character, as in your code.

Said that, the error (if any) is somewhere else.

Comment: OP doesn't want lower case chars

Comment: @Shef: I'm looking at it. Whatever, [remove the @ operator](http://codepad.org/EInLrCd6) to begin with.

Comment: @Shef: I don't know why CodePad triggers a warning. It's running PHP/5.2.5 and I don't have such version to test.

Comment: @Shef: I can't get you last comment. What does "to only allow A-Z, ' and -" mean for you?

Comment: It really wont work for me, I just tested your example and it works fine, however when I code it like this if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z'-]+/",$_POST['firstname'])) {
   $error = "BAd";
   
  } it doesnt work...

Comment: @Daniel: Code in comments is unreadable but you can update the question and add code there. I sugest you use `var_dump()` to inspect the value of `$_POST['firstname']`.

Answer (score 1):

`"/[^a-zA-Z'-]+/"` actually matches everything but `a-zA-z'-`, if you put the ^ in to indicate the start-of-string, you should put it outside the brackets.
Also, the `'-` part of your expression is possibly being interpreted as a range, so you should escape the `-` as @Tom answered or escape the `,` as someone else answered

Answer (score 1):

From what I see. Following Regex should work fine:

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Z\'\-]+$/",$firstname)) {
    // do something
}
```

Here I have escaped both apostrophe and dash. I have tested this in an online Regex tester and works just fine.

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp should look like this:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z\'-]+$/",$firstname);
```

maches: `AB` `A-B` `AB-'`

does not match: `Ab` `a-B` `AB#` `<empty string>`

Comment: Thanks, That does allow an ' but it also allows an '@' sign as well

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]*$/", $firstname)) {
    // do something here
}
```

I have used this, This will work fine. Use It.

Comment: "I have used this, This will work fine. Use It." what kind of comment is that. Could you please add some explanation why this code does what the author of the question wants?

Comment: Do you really know people who's names are `()+` or `{;:$@` ?