# How to validate if a string in PHP only contains letters, single quotes and dash

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to allow A-Z, - and '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385420/regex-to-allow-a-z-and)

I have a form that asks for a name, and the name must not contain any numbers but can have a (') or a (-) e.g O'Neal, O-man.

I've already used `is_string()` but it seems to be strict, does any one of you know how to validate a string that accepts those kinds of values?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: What about william henry gates 3rd?

Comment: I hope this is not a database for real people. Otherwise, please read this: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\\- \']+$/",$name)) {
  echo "Invalid";
}
else {
  echo "Valid";
}
```